# How to make hyperlinks dynamic?

Tags: php

How can I configure the id so that the `$menu` variables output the a value corresponding to their Id. What currently happens is that the id value changes when the e.g. `pid=1`, `pid=7` but the `$type` doesnt change according to the ID.Therefore, the `$type` is not dynamic. How do I make `$type` dynamic?

Code:

```
 if (!isset($_GET["pid"]) && !isset($_GET["type"])){
 $pageid="1";
   $type="";
  }else{
 $pageid=$_GET["pid"];
 $type=$_GET["pid"];
 }
$query = "SELECT Type FROM cart WHERE id='$pageid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 $type = $row['Type'];

 }
```

$menu= '' . $type . '';
$menu2= '' . $type . '';

The problem occurs when I add the $menu and $menu2 variables because they output the same $type value. but the pid value is the dynamic

```
 <div class="clickerdown"></div>

  <div class="seperator"><div class="text"><?php echo $menu; ?></div></div>
 <div class="clickerdown"></div>


  <div class="clickerdown2"></div>

 <div class="seperator2"><div class="text1"></div><?php echo $menu2; ?></div>
  <div class="clickerdown2"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is kind of weird...  You're defining `$pid`, but never using it.  You hardcoded your `id`s into your URLs.  `$type` should be dynamic since it is coming from your `while` loop.  If it isn't, then you need to look at the data in your database and the context of the query that is returning the data you are expecting.

Comment: Probably You need to make 2 cycles, if You would like to build an hierarchical menu.

Comment: I want to ensure the value of `$menu` and `$menu2` give different values but they are giving the same values.

Comment: You're overwriting the variables each time through the loop. When you finally use `$menu` and `$menu2`, they just contain the values from the last row. You need to build the entire menu inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following:

```
$query = "SELECT id, type FROM cart";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_**assoc**($result)) {
  $pid = $row['id'];
  $type = $row['type'];
  //etc
}
```

Using 'mysql_fetch_assoc' will return each row as an associative array.

Hope that helps. :D

Also, you have the menu variables inside the while loop. Those will get reassigned each pass.

[Further info on the php.net website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Read the doc of `mysql_fetch_array()`. It defaults to `MYSQL_BOTH`, so it returns both named and numeric keys.

Comment: ha...just saw this also. another thought....

`//while in the loop
$menu[] = '<a>...</a>'; //your normal link info
`

then after the loop, you have an array `$menu` with each link being an element.

Comment: The fetch_assoc makes no difference. I have added an if condition which changes the values on the html hyperlinks but now the '$type' values change identical to eachother.